# Retreiving Integrated Fitted Data from Stationary Fitted Data

Tags: r, arima, fitting, stationarity

Note that this is a simplified example:

I have some time series that I made stationary by differencing twice. Then I ran `arima` on it, and set d = 0 to prevent additional differencing (I'm aware that `auto.arima` could detect the order of integration, but I'm hard-coding this myself for other reasons). Now I want to use `fitted` data from my `arima` object to determine what the *non-stationary* fit would look like.

For example:

```
library('forecast')
# simulate ARIMA(1,2,0) time series:
rawData <- arima.sim(n = 20, list(order = c(1,2,0), ar = 0.7)) 
# use diff function to make the series stationary:
stationaryData <- diff(diff(rawData))

# fit ARIMA on them appropriately
rawDataFit <- arima(rawData, c(1,2,0)) # include.mean = FALSE by default
stationaryDataFit <- arima(stationaryData, c(1,0,0), include.mean = FALSE) # stationaryData is already twice differenced

# notice that there is very small variance between the AR(1) coefficients:
coef(rawDataFit)
coef(stationaryDataFit)
```

In this particular instance, my AR(1) coefficeints are 0.5511049 and 0.5511048. I also forced my ARIMA to exclude an intercept, so these ARIMA objects so be similar.

```
# plot of rawData and the fitted values
plot(rawData, type = "l")
lines(fitted(rawDataFit), col = "slategrey")
```

Here's an example of what that plot could look like:
[image: Here's an example of what that plot could look like]

I want to recreate the above plot, *without* using the rawDataFit object

```
# using the diffinv function, I can easily replicate the rawData:
recoveredRawData <- diffinv(stationaryData, differences = 2, xi = rawData[1:2])

# Now I also want to "recover" the non-stationary data from the fitted AR(1) object:
recoveredFit <- diffinv(fitted(stationaryDataFit), differences = 2, xi = c(0,0))

# plot of rawData and the fitted values
plot(recoveredRawData, type = "l")    
lines(recoveredFit, col = "slategrey")
```

Here's the attempt to recreate the above plot, using the results from my stationaryDataFit:

[image: Here's the attempt to recreate the above plot, using the results from my stationaryDataFit]

The shape looks correct, but the values are clearly off. I am *not* expecting to recover exactly the same results from both methods of fitting, but I still expect them to be reasonably close.

I strongly suspect the problem is with my choice of xi in the `diffinv` function, since that's really the only place I'm making any assumptions. But I'm having trouble reconciling the issue.

To integrate the data, `diffinv` requires the first observations of the integrated data. This is how I can convert the stationaryData back to the rawData, by passing the first two values of rawData to the `diffinv` xi argument. But I'm unsure what to use as the starting values to integrate `fitted(stationaryDataFit)`. The first two values of the (integrated) rawData are 0, so that's what I'm trying for now...

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Is this a legitimate work-around? Take the residuals from my stationaryDataFit object, and just subtract those from my rawData? For example:

```
# prefix 2 zeros, so the vectors are the same length (due to secord-differencing):
recoveredFit <- rawData - c(rep(0, 2), stationaryDataFit$residuals)
```

My concern is about whether I need to transform my residuals from the stationaryDataFit somehow? In fact, the residuals from both fits are extremely close (within several decimals).

Thank you!